# ExpressJS & Mongoose performance issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, openshift

For the results from the "db" and "mongo" I have to wait for 2-4 minutes.

Response from */db* should be empty.
But */mongo* should find one item and it does.

```
[
    {
        "created_at":"2016-03-07T12:03:06.797Z",
        "updated_at":"2016-03-07T12:03:06.797Z",
        "name":"Chris-dude",
        "username":"sevilayha",
        "password":"password",
        "_id":"56dd6dfaf12045d5621260fe",
        "__v":0
    }
]
```

Response from */db*

> Proxy Error
>
> The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
>   The proxy server could not handle the request GET /db.
>
> Reason: Error reading from remote server
>
> Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at  Port 80

In /db I want to save item only, if it not exist in my MongoDB.

//server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var mongoose= require('mongoose');
var User = require('./app/models/user');


//logs      
var logs = {};
function log(key, value){
    logs[key]=value;
}

//app configuration
var ipaddr = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1';
var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;

//mongodb configuration
var mongoHost = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST || 'localhost';
var mongoPort = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT || 27017;
var mongoUser = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME; //mongodb username
var mongoPass = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD; //mongodb password
var mongoDb   = process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME; //mongodb database name

//connection strings
var mongoString = 'mongodb://' + mongoUser + ':' + mongoPass + '@' + mongoHost + ':' + mongoPort + '/' + mongoDb;


mongoose.connect(mongoString, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        log('createConnection err',err);
    }
});


var chris = new User({
  name: 'Chris',
  username: 'sevilayha',
  password: 'password' 
});

log('chris',chris);

chris.dudify(function(err, name) {
  if (err) throw err;
  log('Your new name is ' + name);
});


app.get('/db', function(req, res) {
    User.find({ username: 'sevilayha' }, function(err, user) {
       if (err) throw err;  
       if(user.length == 0){
            chris.save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    log('User saved successfully!',err);   
                    throw err;    
                }
            });
       } else {
      // object of the user
        log('search result',user);
           res.status(200).send(user);
           res.end();
       }
    });  
});

app.get('/logs', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send(logs);
});


// app is running!
app.get('/', function(req, res) { 
  res.status(200).send('OK');
});


app.get('/mongo', function(req, res) {
  User.find({ username: 'sevilayha'}, function(err, data){
    if (err) {
        log('User.find err',err);
      res.status(500).send('NOT OK' + JSON.stringify(err));
    } else {
        log('user.find data',data);
        res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(data));
        res.end();
    }
  });
});

app.listen(port, ipaddr);
```

//app/models/user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  admin: Boolean,
  location: String,
  meta: {
    age: Number,
    website: String
  },
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date
});

userSchema.methods.dudify = function() {
  this.name = this.name + '-dude'; 
};

// on every save, add the date
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {

  var currentDate = new Date(); 
  this.updated_at = currentDate;
  if (!this.created_at)    this.created_at = currentDate;
  next();
});


var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

What am I doing wrong?

**edit:**

add res.end();

Comment: Nothing is really alarming about your code, but 2-4 minutes seems extremely high. What happens when you run the code and mongo locally? Have you indexed the `username` field? How many records are in your db?

Comment: Can you please try indexing username field like db.collection.createIndex( { username: 1 } ) in mongo shell and try to check performance

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the index in 1 element db is the response far from the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is your `/db` route isn't letting the request know that it's finished processing, so the request from Apache is timing out. You should add a `res.end()` in that route when the database operations are finished

Comment: Thx for this tip. Now I have response after a second. 
My second issue is now this 502 after calling `/db`. I will try to check it out more.

Answer (score 0):

I have the result: I declared chris as a local variable, so calling chris.save() inside of `/db` caused the error. Unfortunately, this error wasn't in the logs.
I checked it with `/newTom` - it's always working.

```
   var chris = new User({ //local variable!
      name: 'Chris',
      username: 'sevilayha',
      password: 'password' 
    });

    chris.dudify(function(err, name) {
      if (err) throw err;
      log('Your new name is ' + name);
    });

    tom = new User({  //global
      name: 'Tom',
      username: 'Jonson',
      password: 'admin1' 
    });

    tom.dudify(function(err, name) {
      if (err) throw err;
      log('Your new name is ' + name);
    });

app.get('/db', function(req, res) {



    User.find({ username: 'sevilay' }, function(err, user) {
       if (err) throw err;  
       if(user.length == 0){
            chris.save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    log('User saved successfully!',err);   
                    throw err;    
                }
            });
       } else {
      // object of the user
        log('search result',user);
           res.status(200).send(user);
           res.end();
       }
    });  
});

app.get('/newTom', function(req, res) {

    User.find({ username: 'Jonson' }, function(err, user) {
       if (err) throw err;  
       if(user.length == 0){
            tom.save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    log('User saved successfully!',err);   
                    throw err;    
                }
            });
       } else {
        log('search result',user);
           res.status(200).send(user);
           res.end();
       }
    });  
});
```